# Users on boot screen don't refresh

Tags: startup, user-account, filevault

I'm running macOS 10.13 on a MacBook. Users & Groups show me one Current User and a deactivated Guest User:

[image: users and groups]

but on the boot screen another user shows up, that I had added and removed a few weeks ago:

[image: boot screen]

Tried to add a user and that won't show up on the boot screen. How do I refresh that?

I'd also like to remove the "Disk Password" option to just have the user and password field directly open, without the need to click on it first.

[image: options]

Comment: Just to be clear this isn’t a mdm managed system or have had hidden users added? Also, if you add a new user and reboot, that adds ok and then remove that user and reboot, that refreshes ok as well?

Comment: Nope, not a managed system. Was using the Beta for some time when I added the user. Adding a user and rebooting doesn’t change the boot user selection. Also I’m wondering how to get rid of the hard drive icon, to have a password prompt only.